# Convergence of a crazy power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

"Let $\alpha$ be a given real number, $\alpha>0$ and $\alpha \notin \Bbb{N}$. Proof that the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)(\alpha-2)\dots(\alpha-(n-1))}{n!}x^n$$
converges for $|x| \leq 1$ and diverges for $|x|>1$."
It's easy to show that this power series converges for $|x|<1$. We have just to use the formula for the convergence radius
$$R=\lim _{n \to +\infty} \left| \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right|$$
for $a_n=\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)(\alpha-2)\dots(\alpha-(n-1))}{n!}$, in this case. Using that, we find $R=1$. The trouble is to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}a_nx^n$ converges for $|x|=1\dots$

Comment: Doesn't the ratio test say you have to consider $\lim _{n \to +\infty} \left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|$?

Comment: This is quickly decided with [Raabe's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#Raabe.27s_test).

Comment: Is this really true? Consider the power series for $(1+x)^{1/2}$. I think there may be trouble at $x=-1$.

Comment: You're right, @graydad, the ratio test considers the limit $\lim _{n \to +\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|$ and the RADIUS of convergence of a power series is given by $\lim_{n\to+\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}}\right|$. Both of these limits are 1.

Comment: @AndréNicolas For $\alpha > 0$, it's fine in $x = -1$, the function has a zero there.

Comment: @DanielFischer, to use the Raabe's Test (in the case $x=1$), we must have $a_n>0$. How do we garantee this here?

Comment: No, Raabe's test is a test for absolute convergence, so it doesn't require $a_n > 0$.

Comment: Oh, now I see... If we proof that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}|a_n|$ converges, so does the series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}a_n$ (due to the absolute convergence...) Thanks @DanielFischer!

Answer (score 4):

In order to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}a_nx^n$ converges for $|x|=1$, i.e., for $x=1$ or $x=-1$ we can use Raabe's Test to show that both of these series,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}a_n \text{ and} \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}a_n(-1)^n$$
converges.
First, note that $\left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=|\frac{a_{n+1}(-1)^{n+1}}{a_n(-1)^n}|$. So, the limit involved in Raabe's Test gives the same computation for both of these series.
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}n\left(1-\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|\right)=\lim_{n\to+\infty}n\left(1-\left|\frac{\alpha\dots(\alpha-n)}{(n+1)!}\cdot\frac{n!}{\alpha\dots(\alpha-(n-1)}\right|\right)$$
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}n\left(1-\left|\frac{\alpha-n}{n+1}\right|\right)=\lim_{n\to+\infty}n\left(1-\frac{n-\alpha}{n+1}\right)=\lim_{n\to+\infty}n\left(\frac{n+1+\alpha-n}{n+1}\right)$$
$$=1+\alpha>1,\text{ since $\alpha>0.$}$$
Thus, by Raabe's Test, the series converges for $|x|=1$. The series diverges for $|x|>1$ obviously because these $x$ are outside the convergence radius.
Note that $a_n$ is never zero, since $\alpha \notin \Bbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a direct approach I wanted to share with you.

First, let $\alpha>1$. Then with $k=\lfloor\alpha\rfloor$, we have
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{|a_n|}{\alpha(\alpha-1)} &= \frac{\alpha-2}{1}\cdot\frac{\alpha-3}{2}\cdots\frac{\alpha-k}{k-1}
\cdot\frac{k-\alpha+1}{k}\cdot\frac{k-\alpha+2}{k+1}\cdots\frac{k-\alpha+(n-1-k)}{n-2}\cdot\frac1{(n-1)n}\\
&\leq\frac{\alpha-2}{1}\cdot\frac{\alpha-3}{2}\cdots\frac{\alpha-k}{k-1}\cdot\frac1{(n-1)n} 
\end{split}
$$
making the convergence obvious.

Now assume $0<\alpha<1$.
Then we have
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{|a_n|}{\alpha(1-\alpha)} &= \frac{2-\alpha}{1}\cdot\frac{3-\alpha}{2}\cdots\frac{n-1-\alpha}{n-2}\cdot\frac1{(n-1)n} \\
&=\big(1+\beta\big)\big(1+\frac\beta2\big)\cdots\big(1+\frac\beta{n-1}\big)\cdot\frac1{(n-1)n}
\end{split}
$$
where $\beta=1-\alpha\in(0,1)$. From the Maclaurin series of $\log(1+x)$, i.e., from Mercator's series, we have the inequality
$$
\log(1+x)< x \qquad \textrm{for} \quad 0<x\leq1 , 
$$
which implies
$$
\log\big(1+\beta\big)+\log\big(1+\frac\beta2\big)+\ldots\log\big(1+\frac\beta{n-1}\big)\leq\beta\big(1+2+\ldots+\frac1{n-1}\big) .
$$
Then taking into account
$$
2+\ldots+\frac1{n-1}\leq\int_1^{n-1}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}x = \log(n-1) ,
$$
we have
$$
\log\big(1+\beta\big)+\log\big(1+\frac\beta2\big)+\ldots\log\big(1+\frac\beta{n-1}\big)\leq\beta\big(1+\log(n-1)\big) 
\leq\beta\log(ne),
$$
or
$$
\big(1+\beta\big)\big(1+\frac\beta2\big)\cdots\big(1+\frac\beta{n-1}\big)
\leq e^{\,\beta} n^{\,\beta} .
$$
Finally, this gives
$$
|a_n| \leq \frac{C\,n^{\,\beta}}{n^{\,2}} = \frac{C}{n^{1+\alpha}} ,
$$
for some constant $C>0$.